# Getting sub element attribute with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm looping through a long list of `host` elements with `lxml etree` like this:

```
for host in xml.iter('host'):
```

Each element looks like this:

```
<host status="up" />
   <address addr="84.20.200.143" addrtype="ipv4" />
</host>
```

I've been reading the official docs trying to figure out how to get the `addr` of each sub-element `address`, but after a dozen tries I can't wrap my head around it. How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

An XPATH selector may get you what you want. Suppose I want a list of addresses for hosts that are up. I could do:

```
for addr in xml.xpath('//host[@status="up"]/address/@addr'):
    print(addr)
```

If I want all addresses I coud do:

```
for addr in xml.xpath('//host/address/@addr'):
    print(addr)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through your xml, you need to use `attrib.get('addr')` on the tag you are looking to analyze.

Here is a functional example of what you are trying to do:

```
s = """<host status="up">
   <address addr="84.20.200.143" addrtype="ipv4" />
</host>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(s))
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)

for i in root:
    print(i.attrib.get('addr'))
```

Output: 84.20.200.143

I believe you can also use `find` on the root node you are on to find tags within that root. But behind the scenes, this is most likely iterating to look for the tag as well. Nonetheless:

```
d = root.find('address').attrib.get('addr')
```

Extra information. Look at this, this should provide more info. From the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements

Comment: So even if I nkow there's only one `address` tag in a `host`, I can't access it directly? I have to loop through the sub-elements? In reality there are many `host` in my file, each with more than one sub-element (in this case I only showed one sub-element).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for host in xml.iter('host'):
    for child in host:
        print child.attrib['addr']
```

It iterates through the child element of `host`, which is `address`, and then print the `addr` attrib

Comment: Can we not access `address` by name? In my actual case, there's more than one sub-element, do I have to iterate through each and check if `name == 'address'` ?

Comment: Change the second loop to `for child in host.iter('address')`.

Comment: @warmoverflow no better than lxml. I don't see how a different horse is any better.

Comment: @tdelaney yes I saw your answer and removed mine :)